# TYPO3 on XAMPP: Changes in backend not/unreliably persisted

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, typo3, typo3-9.x

### Context

I've a running **TYPO3 project** on a **Linux webserver** and now I'm trying to get it working properly on a **local Windows 10 machine with XAMPP** for development purposes.

**What I've done**

1. Copied all content from webserver storage to local `xampp/htdocs/typo3` folder
2. Exported and imported database content from server database to local database
3. Adapted database info in `typo3/typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php`
4. Configured the local XAMPP / PHP / MySQL so that they are the same versions as on the server

**The versions are:**

- TYPO3-Version: 9.5.13
- Webserver: Apache/2.4.41 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1c PHP/7.3.25
- PHP-Version   7.3.25
- Database: MySQL 5.7.31

### Problem

In general everything works, and also `Environment -> Check Environment` in TYPO3 Backend doesn't show errors or warnings. However, if I **change some page or content in the backend this is horribly unreliable**:

- Hiding a page (context menu -> hide) is not reflected in the UI (no red symbol at the page icon), also after F5 in backend, only after Ctrl+F5 in Chrome (clear cache and reload), the red symbol indicating the page is hidden shows up
- Hiding a content element of a page doesn't work at all, event after Ctrl + F5 the element still shows up as "not hidden"
- However, if I hide an element in the "Page" view and afterwards switch to the "List" view (Menu "Web" on the left), in the List view, it is shown as "hidden". The element is also hidden on the frontend page.
- "De-hiding" the element in the "List" view correctly updates the backend UI (also after F5), but on frontend the element is still hidden, even after "Flush all caches" and Ctrl + F5
- Adding a new element on "Page" view, does not update Page view, but new element is visible in "List" view and in frontend
- Already deleted elements randomly re-appear in List view
- The same problems occur for newly created pages, not only on altering existing ones
- No error or warning messages in Typo3 log, Apache log or MySQL log
- All these things work without problems on the remote server

Maybe I should just file a bug for TYPO3, but maybe somebody has a hint for me what I could try on my part to fix this problem. However since it's working on the remote server, it seems like a configuration issue and not a TYPO3 bug. I've run out of ideas.

---

**Updates based on comments:**

- Network requests for hiding an element on remote server look like this: http://prntscr.com/vtojzk
- Network requests locally look like this: http://prntscr.com/vtoniv , details: http://prntscr.com/vtonzy -> so this request is cancelled for whatever reason.

Comment: Can you check the network pane and look for cache-related headers? Maybe something overrides the defaults of TYPO3. There should be a `Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate` here.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! On requests to `index.php` exactly these headers are present, on other resources like images not. But since the problem also exist with devtools network tab open and checked "disable cache" in Chrome, it should not be a browser-cache issue. See the update in the question, where I've found a cancelled request in the network tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I switched from XAMPP to [Laragon](https://laragon.org/), where all the errors disappeared. Don't ask me why and what's the difference there, versions are nearly the same:

- TYPO3 Version: 9.5.13
- Webserver: Apache/2.4.35 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1h PHP/7.3.25
- Database: MySQL 5.7.24